# 2 CSS files, 1 for mobile and 1 for computers

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have 2 CSS files, 1 for mobile devices and 1 for computers, laptops..
See below:

http://www.townhouseistanbul.com/skin/kevintimmer/css/tablet.css
http://www.townhouseistanbul.com/skin/kevintimmer/css/large.css

Is it posible to load tablet.css only on mobile devices, and not when a user make his screen smaller on a computer.

Code below didnt work for me :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.townhouseistanbul.com/skin/kevintimmer/css/large.css" type="text/css" media="Screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.townhouseistanbul.com/skin/kevintimmer/css/tablet.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use media queries ? it will provide you the same visual effect

Comment: If you don't want your site to be responsive (i.e. adapting with the change of the viewport size) you have to rely on a server side solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<link id="stylesheet-tablet" media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 979px)" href="tablet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="stylesheet-mobile" media="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px)" href="mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and use this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

Comment: min width for mobile is unnecessary

Comment: For a better understanding

Comment: Its not working, computer browser is good, but on mobile its not responsive

Comment: Oke, that work for me, but the problem is, when i resize my browser it change te layout. I only want the mobile stylesheets on mobile devices

Comment: you want only page allow mobile for example you want mobile site? when you resize page browser not load other css and load mobile css

Comment: you must use server side language e.g php i am php developer if you want edit post with php code??

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library to [detect mobile browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) and load the correct CSS

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution,

Use

```
max-device-width
```

instead of

```
(max-width: 480px)
```

Thanks for help